# Use list item at nth position from an if statement match

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, list-comprehension

I have a list with text elements in it.
Say:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 're_match', 'd', 'line_to_extract_1', 'f', 'g', 're_match', 'i',
           'line_to_extract_2', 'k']
```

I want to match at `re_match` for all the occurrences in the list, using regex, and take the `i+2`th element for storing in a new list. I want to do this using list comprehensions.

The output should look like:

```
new_list = ['line_to_extract_1', 'line_to_extract_2',...]
```

I found out about the `enumerate` function but am not sure of how to use it (or if it will serve the purpose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this list-comprehension as long as you can guarantee that there is always an item available to extract two positions after each `match_item`:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 're_match', 'd', 'line_to_extract_1', 'f', 'g','re_match', 'i', 'line_to_extract_2', 'k']
match_item = 're_match'

new_list = [my_list[i+2] for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == match_item]
# ['line_to_extract_1', 'line_to_extract_2']
```

Comment: `i,x in enumerate(my_list,2)` ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, that looks neat; avoids +2.

Comment: You can avoid an `IndexError` from lists which are too short by using `[my_list[i+2] for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == match_item and i+2 < len(my_list)]`

Answer (score 1):

I can't clearly understand what is the question about. If you're asking, how the `enumerate` function works, you can either check it in this way:

```
print(list(enumerate(your_list)))
```

or watch [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

The solution for your task is possible without `enumerate`, as for me, it's easier to read the code if there're only indexes or only values with no mixing:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 're_match', 'd', 'line_to_extract_1', 'f', 'g', 're_match', 'i',
       'line_to_extract_2', 'k']
match = 're_match'
y = [x[i + 2] for i in range(len(x) - 2) if match == x[i]]
```